# Boostrap 3 Popover Misalignment on First Load for Large Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm embedding an iframe into a popover whose trigger button will be placed at the upper-right corner of an app. The size of the iframe is larger than the usual popover content.

When the popover first loads, its arrow and content area are misaligned, but on subsequent loads, the content area gets a hold of the size of its content.

How can I fix this on first load?

Here's a sample code: 
jsfiddle.net/creativediego/uq8o2h1d/2/

Comment: Please add your code to the question (and add an actual link to your jsfiddle).

Comment: For a new user, this site makes it too complicated to add code...
[link] http://jsfiddle.net/creativediego/uq8o2h1d/2/